# How do I replace a value in a matrix/dataframe if that value is less than the corresponding value in a list?

Tags: r

I have a (20x12)matrix with numerical values and a list of 12 numbers. If a value in the matrix is less than the value in the list in the corresponding column index, I would like to replace it. How can I do it?

```
mat <- matrix(rpois(240,10),ncol=12)

list_to_replace <- rpois(12,10)
```

Comment: So you have 20 rows in your matrix are you asking to replace any value in each of the rows where that value is less than the same indexed positioned value in the "list-to-replace"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what is desired. Use the same logical index to pick out the positions of the possible replacements and the re-assignments:

```
t( apply(mat, 1, function(r) {
       r[ r < list_to_replace] <- list_to_replace[ r < list_to_replace]; r}) )
```

The `t` is needed to transpose back because the apply function always delivers column-oriented result, even when the input is rowwise.

BTW; you would be well advised to only use the term "list" when referring to an R object with class "list". What you have is a "vector".

Answer (score 1):

You could use the code below:

```
index <- t(t(mat) < list_to_replace)
mat[index] <- list_to_replace[which(index, TRUE)[, 2]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately giving me the error ``Error in which(index, TRUE) : object 'index' not found``

Comment: @purple1437 check the edit. This method is faster